# Duvida relacionamento One to Many

Tags: laravel

Fala guys, beleza? Seguinte, to batendo cabeça com o seed do meu BD no laravel, acredito que quem tenha mais experiencia com o framework saiba resolver.

Tenho a model Pessoa com relacionamento One to Many para outras duas (Profissional e Cliente). 
Na hora de realizar a migração, acaba que as pessoas cadastradas acabam sendo profissionais e clientes ao mesmo tempo, pois levam os mesmos ids, como eu determino, por exemplo, de 10 registro do id 1 ao 5 serão clientes e do id 6 ao 10 serão profissionais?

```
class Pessoa extends Model {

public function cliente()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Cliente');
}

public function profissional()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profissional');
}
}
```

Model Profissional

```
class Profissional extends Model
{
public function pessoa(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pessoa');
}
```

Model Cliente

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
public function pessoa(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente');
}
}
```

Meu seed ( Aqui o erro >:p )

```
factory(App\Pessoa::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($u) { 
$u->cliente()->
save(factory(App\Cliente::class)->make());
$u->profissional()->
save(factory(App\Profissional::class)->make());  
});
```

Comment: Outra idéia, mas não testei se funcionaria, qual seria a possibilidade de por um condicional aí dentro dessa factory e de acordo com o $id, mandar para a regra correta?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer os processos separados, já que a Pessoa nunca é cliente e profissional ao mesmo tempo. Exemplo:

```
 factory(App\Pessoa::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($u) { 
    $u->cliente()->save(factory(App\Cliente::class)->make());
 });

 factory(App\Pessoa::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($u) { 
    $u->profissional()->save(factory(App\Profissional::class)->make());  
 });
```

Você poderia, também, fazer as factories dentro de um for, com a contagem e as regras que você citou, porém acho que será mais chato de manter.